# Why surface tension behaves so differently?

Tags: classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, surface-tension, popular-science

When a needle (or any other object) floats on water, its acting upwards balancing the gravity.

[image]

But when an object (or may be a needle suspended in water) submerged in water, it acts downwards.

[image]

Why Surface Tension behaves differently ?

Answer (score 2):

The direction of the force due to surface tension depends on whether the liquid wets the the body or not.

In the first picture liquid does not wet the body, so the force is directed in such a way as to decrease the contact surface area of the body with the liquid. That is, upwards.

In the second picture liquid wets the body, so the force is directed in such a way as to increase the contact surface area of the body with the liquid. That is, downwards.

Whether liquid wets the body or not depends on the surface of the body. If the body, the liquid and the atmosphere are the same in both pictures, the liquid will wet the body either in both pictures (both forces are upwards), or in neither one (both forces are downwards).